# ogg files return wrong mime apache. breaks firefox audio player

Tags: apache-2.2, mime

Hi my site is server ogg files with the mime `application/x-unknown-content-type` instead of `application/ogg` which breaks firefox's audio player. How do i get apache to serve the right mime? would it be easier to write code in my webapp (asp.net) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AddType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) to force a MIME type, or you can update your [magic file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime_magic.html#mimemagicfile).

Comment: as much as it looks correct it doesnt seem to work. I couldnt find the magic file so i tried `AddType audio/ogg .ogg` in `<VirtualHost *:80>` and then `<Directory /var/www/site>`. In both cases i did not get audio/ogg. I cleared my cache and did a number of things to check. No luck. I did restart apache everytime i modified the file.

Comment: I think mod_mono is interfering with it. I made a subdomain for a nonasp site and apache gave the right mime without me doing anything. I setup a subdomain on my asp.net site and for some reason any non root page goes to mono. This isnt code. I think your answer is correct.